# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when setting SelectedValue of DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dropdown

I'm working on a project where I have a DropDownList control in an ASP.NET web application. The SelectedValue property of the DropDownList is causing an ArgumentOutOfRangeException with the message "'DropDownListRab' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items."

Here is the relevant code:

```
Protected Sub GridViewItems_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    ' Put the row into edit mode
    GridViewItems.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex

    ' Re-bind the GridView to show the row in edit mode
    Dim orderID As Integer = Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("orderID"))
    GridViewItems.DataSource = GetOrderItems(orderID)
    GridViewItems.DataBind()
        ' Exception occurs on the line above.
End Sub
```

and

```
...
Dim discount As Decimal? = If(row("Rab, %") Is DBNull.Value, Nothing, CType(row("Rab, %"), Decimal?))

        ' Set text of Label control for discount
        Dim labelDiscount As Label = CType(e.Row.FindControl("LabelDiscount"), Label)
        If discount.HasValue Then
            labelDiscount.Text = discount.Value.ToString() & "%"
        Else
            labelDiscount.Text = "0%"
        End If
...
```

So that in my GridView the data in column 'Rab, %' is shown like 30,00%, 20,00% etc.

And here is the markup for the DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListRab" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("[Rab, %]") %>'>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="0%" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="10%" Value="10.00"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="20%" Value="20.00"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="30%" Value="30.00"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="40%" Value="40.00"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="50%" Value="50.00"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="60%" Value="60.00"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="70%" Value="70.00"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="80%" Value="80.00"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="90%" Value="90.00"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="100%" Value="100.00"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

I have checked that the list items of the DropDownList are properly populated with valid values, including the one specified by the SelectedValue. However, I still receive the ArgumentOutOfRangeException when attempting to access the SelectedValue in the RowEditing event handler.

Also my data in database for the column [Rab, %] is *NULL*, 10.00, 20.00, 30.00 etc.

What could be causing this issue? How can I resolve it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You will want to look at the value of `orderID` while your program is in break mode. Then you will want to be sure that is a valid number for `GetOrderItems`, which I don't see in your provided code.

Comment: This really isn't a sql server question.

Comment: Think there is some detail missing here.  From the code, can't see any attempt to either set or read DropDownListRab.SelectedValue.  When exactly is this exception actually occurring?  Is it possible this exception is happening somewhere in the page loading before the data source for DropDownListRab has finished been set?